# Line Segment Circle Intersection

Tags: geometry

I am trying to determine the point at which a line segment intersect a circle.  For example, given any point between P0 and P3 (And also assuming that you know the radius), what is the easiest method to determine P3?

[image: Circle]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a system of equations. The circle is defined by: `x^2 + y^2 = r^2`. The line is defined by `y = y0 + [(y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0)]·(x - x0)`.  Substitute the second into the first, you get `x^2 + (y0 + [(y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0)]·(x - x0))^2 = r^2`. Solve this and you'll get 0-2 values for x. Plug them back into either equation to get your values for y.

Comment: When you get two solutions, how will you tell which one is P3 and which one is the corresponding point on the other side of the circle?

Comment: Find the distance between each point and P1. You can calculate the square of the distance by (x3-x1)^2 + (y3-y1)^2, whichever of those is smallest is closer to P1.

Comment: Please note that this solution does not work for the case where x1-x0 is zero!

Answer (score 20):

Generally,

- find the angle between P0 and P1
- draw a line at that angle from P0 at a distance r, which will give you P3

In pseudocode,

```
theta = atan2(P1.y-P0.y, P1.x-P0.x)
P3.x = P0.x + r * cos(theta)
P3.y = P0.y + r * sin(theta)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - trying to draw lines between two circles with the lines directed at the center, but with the endpoints on the *outside* of the circles rather than the actual centers.

Comment: This method is good, but re-structuring it to use rsqrt & normals, instead of atan2+cos+sin & angles, was the ticket for performance for me. Hope it helps someone! :)

Comment: this is correct when p0 is the center of the circle, as the drawing above shows, but the question doesn't seem to be about that

Comment: Maaaan... thanks alot, this answer was really helpful.

Answer (score 11):

From the center of the circle and the radius you can write the equation describing the circle.
From the two points P0 and P1 you can write the equation describing the line.

So you have 2 equations in 2 unknowns, which you can solved through substitution.

> Let (x0,y0) = coordinates of the point P0
>
> And (x1,y1) = coordinates of the point P1
>
> And r = the radius of the circle.

The equation for the circle is:

```
(x-x0)^2 + (y-y0)^2 = r^2
```

The equation for the line is:

```
(y-y0) = M(x-x0)  // where M = (y1-y0)/(x1-x0)
```

Plugging the 2nd equation into the first gives:

```
(x-x0)^2*(1 + M^2) = r^2

x - x0 = r/sqrt(1+M^2)
```

Similarly you can find that

```
y - y0 = r/sqrt(1+1/M^2)
```

The point (x,y) is the intersection point between the line and the circle, (x,y) is your answer.

```
P3 = (x0 + r/sqrt(1+M^2), y0 + r/sqrt(1+1/M^2))
```

Comment: Would that work for perfectly horizontal and vertical lines? I am not good at math, but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 8):

Go for this code..its save the time

```
private boolean circleLineIntersect(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float cx, float cy, float cr ) {
      float dx = x2 - x1;
      float dy = y2 - y1;
      float a = dx * dx + dy * dy;
      float b = 2 * (dx * (x1 - cx) + dy * (y1 - cy));
      float c = cx * cx + cy * cy;
      c += x1 * x1 + y1 * y1;
      c -= 2 * (cx * x1 + cy * y1);
      c -= cr * cr;
      float bb4ac = b * b - 4 * a * c;

         // return false  No collision
         // return true Collision
      return bb4ac >= 0;
    }
```

Comment: This is for line which if different than line-segment.

Comment: this just returns a boolean that says IF there is an intersection, it doesn't return the intersection itself

Comment: Why not replace the bottom 5 lines of the function with `return bb4ac >= 0`?

Answer (score 2):

**MATLAB CODE**

function [ flag] = circleLineSegmentIntersection2(Ax, Ay, Bx, By, Cx, Cy, R)

> % A and B are two end points of a line segment and C is the center of
>   the circle,  % R is the radius of the circle. THis function compute
>   the closest point fron C to the segment % If the distance to the
>   closest point > R return 0 else 1

```
Dx = Bx-Ax;
Dy = By-Ay;

LAB = (Dx^2 + Dy^2);
t = ((Cx - Ax) * Dx + (Cy - Ay) * Dy) / LAB;

if t > 1
    t=1;
elseif t<0
    t=0;
end;


nearestX = Ax + t * Dx;
nearestY = Ay + t * Dy;

dist = sqrt( (nearestX-Cx)^2 + (nearestY-Cy)^2 );

if (dist > R )
 flag=0;
else
 flag=1;
end
```

end